# VBA: declaring/setting global and permanent variable objects and accessing in other Subs/Functions

Tags: vba, declare

I want to declare variable/objects that should be:

- **Global**: I will be able to use them in all Subs/Functions
- **Permanent**: some events trigger those subs and the variable should still be accessible/available to the subs.

The use of `Workbook_Open()` sub is not required, but it was the closest thing I found to a constructor... My simplified structure:

In `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Public HS As Worksheet <-- the global variable

Private Sub WorkbookOpen()
  Set HS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1) 
End Sub
```

In `Module1` :

```
Sub HistCheck()
  HS.Activate <-- Objet required
End Sub
```

Comment: What's your question, exactly?

Comment: Why are you using a variable? If you want sheet 1 just use it's codename `Sheet1.Acivate` - If you have a specific reason for needing this kind of functionality then you need to explain your problem in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place your global variables within a module, not the workbook or sheet*.

In `Modeul1`:

```
Global Public HS As Worksheet
```

Only Modules can declare variables that can be used throughout the worksheet objects, subs, and functions.

You were correct in placing this code under the workbook object

Under `Workbook`:

```
Private Sub WorkbookOpen()
  Set HS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1) 
End Sub
```

With both of these items in the proper locations, you can place your code as follows in any location of the document, as long as the document is loaded in memory of course.

```
Sub HistCheck()
  HS.Activate
End Sub
```

If you have any issues, please write back what the exact error messages are to allow troubleshooting.

Answer (score -2):

Use a factory to initialized your global objects

```
Factory.bas

Public Function GetHS() as WorkSheet
  GetHS = ActiveWorkBook.Sheets(1)
End Function

Module1.bas
Sub HistCheck()
    Factory.GetHS().Activate
End Sub
```